# Scheme not returning 0 false

Tags: scheme

```
(define repl (lambda (env)
    (let* (
        (dummy1 (display "cs305> "))
        (expr (read))
        (new-env (if (define-stmt? expr)
            (extend-env (cadr expr) (s6-interpret (caddr expr) env) env) env)
        )
        (val 
          (cond
             ((define-stmt? expr) (cadr expr))
             ((and (if-stmt? expr) (= (cadr expr) 0) ) (cadddr expr))
             ((and (if-stmt? expr) (not(= (cadr expr) 0)) ) (caddr expr))
             (else (s6-interpret expr env))
          )
        )
        (dummy2 (display "cs305: "))
        (dummy3 (display val))
        (dummy4 (newline))
        (dummy4 (newline)))
    (repl new-env))))
```

Here is how it should be

```
cs305> (if (- 5 x) (+ x 1) (* x 2))
cs305: 10
```

but i get `6` but it is supposed to be `0` because x is defined as `5`. what is wrong with the function here?

Comment: What's the point of all those `dummyX` variables? If you want to execute expressions without using the results, just put them in the body of the `let`.

Comment: I am new to this and this is a homework that is why we have dummies.

so `if-stmt` lines are correct right? How do I use let here? can you please demonstrate I really want to learn @Barmar

Comment: Why do you need the special conditions for `if-stmt?` Doesn't `s6-interpret` know how to interpret `if` expressions?

Answer (score 0):

When processing an `if` statement you need to interpret the condition and the selected consequent. I'm not sure why you're not getting an error from `(= (cadr expr) 0) )`, since `(cadr expr)` is a list, not a number.

```
(define repl (lambda (env)
  (display "cs305> ")
  (let* (
         (expr (read))
         (new-env (if (define-stmt? expr)
                      (extend-env (cadr expr) (s6-interpret (caddr expr) env) env)
                      env)
                  )
         (val 
          (cond
           ((define-stmt? expr) (cadr expr))
           ((if-stmt? expr)
            (if (= (s6-interpret (cadr expr) env) 0)
                (s6-interpret (cadddr expr) env)
                (s6-interpret (caddr expr) env)))
           (else (s6-interpret expr env))
           )
          ))
    (display "cs305: ")
    (display val)
    (newline)
    (newline))
  (repl new-env)))
```